# Get location of Windows context menu selection?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, contextmenu

I have a Windows context menu item invoking a Windows Form via these registry keys...

```
HKLM\Software\Classes\*\shell\myappname
HKLM\Software\Classes\*\shell\myappname\command
```

But when my Windows Form is started, I want it to be located near where the context menu was invoked.  Is there any way to do that?  I think I need to get the coordinates of the Windows event and set the window location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the [MousePosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition.aspx) property to get the current mouse pointer position. That will, at least, reduce the distance the user needs to move the mouse to interact with your Windows Form.

Comment: Agreed.  StartPosition = Manual.

Comment: Reluctantly accepting this...wishing there was a better way :)